# ColorReplace with thresholds and connected components

Tags: image-processing, color

I would like to replace the colors in this drawing (called `img`) with colors of my choice.  (For simplicity, we can assume my desired colors are `ColorData["Rainbow"][i]` for `i = 0, .1, ..., 1`.)

[image: etching]

I have used `DominantColors[img]` to extract the principal colors and then used

```
ColorReplace[img, ...]
```

where the options are a list of associations, where White -> White and each of the remaining principal colors gets mapped to the Rainbow colors.  Alas, because (I think) the distributions of colors are far from uniform, and because the edges of each line "blur" colors, the process never works.  Each line in the drawing that should be a single color gets split.

I've tried `ColorQuantize`, `ConnectedComponents`, `Erosion`, `Dilation`, `Sharpen`, and `EdgeDetection`, in various forms, but never quite get what I seek.

I think I'm missing some image processing function that will sharpen each line and ensure each pixel is quantized to the proper color, but just can't find that function.

Comment: I didn't know `PrincipalColors` , is it a new function in Mathematica 12.3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**modified**

With option `ColorCoverage->0` you get six dominant `colors`.

```
colors = DominantColors[img, ColorCoverage -> 0]
```

Image with this colorspace follows to

```
imgN = ColorQuantize[img, colors]
```

Replace colors( `Hue` instead of `ColorData["Rainbow"]`, shows more effect)

```
subst = MapIndexed[#1 -> Hue[#2[[1]]/Length[Rest[colors]]]&,Rest[colors]]
ColorReplace[imgN, subst]
```

[image]

**"optimized" answer**

`ColorQuantize` together with rainbow color selection returns image with the prescribed colors

```
imgR = ColorQuantize[img,Join[{White},Table[ColorData["Rainbow"][i], {i, 0.1, 1, .1}]]]
DominantColors[imgR, ColorCoverage -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much ($\checkmark$).  `ColorCoverage` was the key I was missing.  (I had never heard of it.)  Indeed, another lookup table besides "Rainbow" is superior, but I proposed that just for simplicity.  Thanks so much.

Comment: nYou're welcome, nice to be able to help